# Rudin exponential function extending $e^n$ to all real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

Rudin is defining the $e^n$ function from the exponential function but I am confused about an unjustified claim he makes about continuity and monotonicity which I have highlighted in yellow. How exactly does he use continuity and monotonicity to define $E(x)=e^x$? I understand that for rationals, we have that $E(p)=e^p$, however how does continuity and monotonicity come into play when extending this definition to all real numbers

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take an increasing sequence of rational numbers $p_n\to x$. Then $E(x_n)=e^{p_n}$, by (32). Taking limits on both sides we get $E(x)=E(\lim_np_n)=\lim_n E(p_n)=\lim_n e^{p_n}=\sup_n e^{p_n}=e^{x}$. The second equation is due to the continuity of $E$. The third equation was (32).

Comment: @plop Why does the sequence have to be increasing?

Comment: @SamKirkiles It doesn't have to be increasing. It is just a choice, a cheap way to be sure that we can replace limit with the supremum that was used to define $e^x$.

Comment: @plop Ah makes sense thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rudin is not proving continuity of $e^x.$ At least, not directly.

> **Assumption 1:** If $f$ is continuous and monotonic increasing, then $$f(x)=\sup_{x>q\in\mathbb Q}f(q).$$

He has previously defined, for $a>1,$ $a^q$ for $q$ rational and defined $$a^x=\sup_{x>q\in\mathbb Q} a^q.$$

At this point, we might know nothing about $a^x$ as a function.  We might not  even know that $a^x<+\infty$ for all real $x.$

In this section, he shows that if $e=E(1)$ then $e>1$ and $e^q=E(q),$ for all rational $q.$

That means $$e^x=\sup_{q<x} e^q=\sup_{q<x} E(q)=E(x).$$

That last equality follows from our assumption because $E$ was shown to be monotonic increasing and continuous.

But now, we know $e^x=E(x)$ for all real $x,$ so we know $e^x$ has all the properties on the reals that $E(x)$ has, including being monotonic increasing and continuous.